Number of tries in key guessing game

That's the game (from Brilliant.com): The key is hidden in this $8\times 8$ matrix. If we looked for the key under a tile, we will not look there again. So after 64 tries, we definitely will have found the key.
How many tries, on average, do we need to find the key?
Brilliant claims that the average is $32$:

But according to my calculation, it would be $32.5$.
Very verbosely, we can calculate the probability that the key is found after $k$ tries; for this, we first we must miss $k-1$ times, and then we must find the key:
$$ \frac{63}{64}\cdot\frac{62}{63}\cdots\frac{64 - k + 1}{64 - k + 2} \cdot \frac{1}{64 - k +1} = \frac{1}{64}\,.$$
Though it is also immediately clear that the probability that the tile checked at the $k$th try has the key, must be equal to all others, so $\frac{1}{64}$.
Therefore, the expected value of tries is $$\frac{1}{64} + \frac{2}{64} + \cdots + \frac{64}{64} = 32.5\,.$$
Now, who is right?

You are correct.

Weird puzzle though... the "grid" or "matrix" has nothing to do with it... the options could be in a line or whatever.

Yes. If you consider $n=2$ then the answer is obviously $1.5$ not $1$.

Kind of surprising that Brilliant would make this kind of goof. It should be obvious that the expected result has to contain a fraction if there are an even number of possible results.

@lulu it's used in preparation for the next state where you play it with a hint like in blind man's buff (giving information how much the uncovered tile is removed from the key).

@QuantumWiz mistakes happen (this is not from the probability course but from the artificial neural network course). I haven't found that many on this site. The bigger problem is more that the question difficulty often oscillates like in the Bridge of Death from “Monty Python and the Holy Grail”: What's your favorite color? What's the capital of Assyria?

Let $f(r)$ be the expected number of tries when there are $r$ tiles remaining.
If there's only one tile, then it must contain the key, so $f(1) = 1$.
Otherwise, use up one try to find the key, and you then have a probability of $\frac{r-1}{r}$ of needing to continue.  So $f$ satisfies the recurrence relation:
$$f(r) = 1 + \frac{r-1}{r}f(r-1)$$
Recursively evaluating the function:
$$f(r) = 1 + \frac{r-1}{r} \left( 1 + \frac{r-2}{r-1}f(r-2) \right)$$
$$= 1 + \frac{r-1}{r} + \frac{r-2}{r}f(r-2)$$
$$= 1 + \frac{r-1}{r} + \frac{r-2}{r} \left( 1 + \frac{r-3}{r-2}f(r-3) \right)$$
$$= 1 + \frac{r-1}{r} + \frac{r-2}{r} + \frac{r-3}{r}f(r-3)$$
$$= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{r-k}{r} + \frac{r-n}{r}f(r-n), n < r$$
Let $n = r - 1$ so that the formula ends with the base case $f(1)$.
$$f(r) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{r-2}\frac{r-k}{r} + \frac{1}{r}f(1)$$
$$= 1 + (r-2) - \frac{1}{r}\sum_{k=1}^{r-2}k + \frac{1}{r}$$
$$= r - 1 - \frac{1}{r}\frac{(r-2)(r-1)}{2} + \frac{1}{r}$$
$$= \frac{2r^2 - 2r - r^2 + 3r - 2 + 2}{2r}$$
$$= \frac{r^2 + r}{2r}$$
$$= \frac{r + 1}{2}$$
So, $f(64) = \frac{65}{2} = 32.5$, which agrees with your answer.

Edit: A much simpler way to achieve the same result is to note that that the number of tiles that need to be unveiled is a uniform distribution of the integers between 1 and 64, inclusive.  The mean of a range of integers is just the mean of its endpoints, so still $32.5$.

Can we say it's trivially obvious that the distribution is uniform? To me it seems only intuitive. OK, I guess one could argue that one would first determines how one would uncover the tiles (not actually uncovering them), which is the same as giving every tile a number. And then the key is a random choice of of one of those numbers, therefore uniform.

@viuser: Shuffle the tiles, arrange them in a line, and do a simple linear search from one end to the other.  Since all tiles are equally likely to have the key, this could take anywhere between 1 and 64 tries, with equal probability.

I was perceiving an ambiguity in the word "tries" (if you fail with all but one key, you know that the last one is the key, so is it a "try" or not), but find after many searches that the general convention is that each key used is a "try"
So yes, your answer of $32.5$ is correct, in general, $\frac1{n}\frac{n(n+1)}2 = \frac{n+1}2$.
In any case, however interpreted, Brilliant solution of $32$ is incorrect.

I guess this has been sort of highlighted but not stated explicitly. Without any information about where the key is, the order of your guesses and the formation of the tiles in the grid does not impact your expected value. You can instead reframe the problem as a string of length 64 with b if the tile is blank, and K if the tile has a key. Then since each position for the key is equally likely, you get that the expected position of the key is the average of the numbers 1-64, namely $\frac{64+1}{2}$= $32.5$ as required.

Perhaps the simplest way to see that your answer is correct is as follows.
Suppose you choose a uniformly random order to look for the tiles in, and following that order you would take $R$ tries to find the key. If instead you'd chosen the reverse order, you'd have taken $n-R+1$ tries. (Each place would be tried in exactly one of the two orderings, except for the place with the key, which is tried in both.) But that is also a uniformly random order, so $\mathbb E(R)=\mathbb E(n-R+1)$, giving $\mathbb E(R)=\frac{n+1}{2}$.
